# using telnet via PHP on localhost(127.0.0.1) over port 11300

Tags: php, localhost, telnet

I have problem to use telnet via PHP on localhost(127.0.0.1) over port 11300

I haven't been using this before, so help would be great.

Here is the code:

```
function sendToSocket($host, $port, $out){
    if(!function_exists('fsockopen'))
        return 'f() doesnt exist !';
    $response = "";
    $fp  = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);
    if(!$fp){
        $response .= "$errstr ($errno)<br/>";
    }else{
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        $response .= fgets($fp);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    if($response)
        return $response;
    else
        return "ERROR";
}
echo sendToSocket('127.0.0.1', 11300, 'stats');
```

I got the "ERROR", thats means that  fgets($fp); doesn't work for me.

When typing in Command Line: telnet 127.0.0.1 11300 everything is OK, so then I can type command "stats" in order to get the result. I am using Ubuntu.

Where is the mistake? 
How to get result like result in Command Line ?

Comment: Maybe you need to send `\n` or something similar to actually tell the other end you've made some input?

Comment: I corrected to:
echo sendToSocket('127.0.0.1', 11300, "stats\r\n");

and it's working,everything is OK,thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add it as an answer below. You can then select it as an answer which will mark this question as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This script reads only one line from the response.

```
$response .= fgets($fp);
```

have to be replaced with something like

```
 while (!feof($fp)) {
  $response .= fgets($fp);
}
```

Comment: I remove that while loop because problem was same.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected code to:

echo sendToSocket('127.0.0.1', 11300, "stats\r\n");

and it's working, everything is OK.

Note: the code doesn't work if you send single quote as output.